# Refactoring javascript

Tags: spacemacs, js2-mode, tern, refactoring

How can I rename functions project wide?

I am using spacemacs and also with tern, and it look like tern can only rename variables.

Comment: Check out js2-mode (this article has a sequel or two): https://emacs.cafe/emacs/javascript/setup/2017/04/23/emacs-setup-javascript.html

Comment: Sorry but, I cant find there anything renaming function in a project.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I misread your question!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could try to use `SPC p R` which runs the command `projectile-replace` this might not be exactly what you want (a specific js refactor tool) but it gets the job done and is language agnostic.

Another more advanced option would be to search the name of that function with helm, once you are in the helm buffer `C-c C-e` runs `helm-ag-edit`, this will give you a buffer with your matches, in this buffer you can run `iedit` and rename that function across different files at once, you will need to `C-c C-c` to persist your changes though. 
I use this all the time (here the link where I first read about this https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs?at=573d831c0cb634927f80545e)

Answer (score 1):

There's the `js2-refactor` package which does many things but doesn't rename functions. Perhaps you could extend it.

Comment: Soon if I already learned to write emacs-lisp.

Comment: If you do javascript, how did you do renaming functions?

Comment: It honestly doesn't come up very often. When it does I just do it the old-fashioned way: rename the function and then go find the callers to change them to match. If it's a codebase I'm familar with then I probably know where all the callers are, and if it's one that I'm new to then I just use grep.